# Json regex deserialization with JSON.Net

Tags: regex, json, json.net

I'm trying to read the following example json from a text file into a string using the JSON.Net parsing library.

Content of C:\temp\regeLib.json

```
{
    "Regular Expressions Library":
    {
      "SampleRegex":"^(?<FIELD1>\d+)_(?<FIELD2>\d+)_(?<FIELD3>[\w\&-]+)_(?<FIELD4>\w+).txt$"
    }
}
```

Example code to try and parse:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.RegexConverter rConv = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.RegexConverter();
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(libPath))
        {
          string foo = reader.ReadToEnd();
          JObject jo = JObject.Parse(foo);//<--ERROR

          //How to use RegexConverter to parse??
          Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader jtr = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(reader);
          JObject test = rConv.ReadJson(jtr);//<--Not sure what parameters to provide
          string sampleRegex = test.ToString();
        }
```

It seems I need to use the converter, I know the code above is wrong, but I can't find any examples that describe how / if this can be done.  Is it possible to read a regular expression token from a text file to a string using JSON.Net?  Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Played with it more and figured out  I had to escape the character classes, once I made the correction below I was able to parse to a JObject and use LINQ to query for the regex pattern.

Corrected content C:\temp\regeLib.json

```
{
    "Regular Expressions Library":
    {
      "SampleRegex":"^(?<FIELD1>\\d+)_(?<FIELD2>\\d+)_(?<FIELD3>[\\w\\&-]+)_(?<FIELD4>\\w+).txt$"
    }
}
```

Corrected code

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(libPath))
        {
          string content = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
          JObject regexLib = JObject.Parse(content);
          string sampleRegex = regexLib["Regular Expressions Library"]["SampleRegex"].ToString();

          //Which then lets me do the following...
          Regex rSampleRegex = new Regex(sampleRegex);

          foreach (string sampleFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(dirSampleFiles, "*"))
          {
            filename = Path.GetFileName(sampleFilePath);
            if (rSampleRegex.IsMatch(filename))
            {
              //Do stuff...
            }
          }
        }
```

Not sure if this is the best approach, but it seems to work for my case.

Answer (score -1):

i don't understand why you have to store such a small regex in a json file, are you going to expand the regex in the future?

if so, rather than doing this

```
JObject regexLib = JObject.Parse(content);
string sampleRegex = regexLib["Regular Expressions Library"]["SampleRegex"].ToString();
```

Consider using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to make classes, at least it's strongly-typed and make it more maintainable.

I think a more appropriate json would look like this (assumptions):

```
{
    "Regular Expressions Library": [
        {
          "SampleRegex": "^(?<FIELD1>\\d+)_(?<FIELD2>\\d+)_(?<FIELD3>[\\w\\&-]+)_(?<FIELD4>\\w+).txt$"
        },
        {
          "SampleRegex2": "^(?<FIELD1>\\d+)_(?<FIELD2>\\d+)_(?<FIELD3>[\\w\\&-]+)_(?<FIELD4>\\w+).txt$"
        }
    ]
}
```

It would make more sense this way to store a regex in a "settings" file